# Excel Vba compare 2 values from different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba, powershell, match

I am working with two excel files, one is generated by an imported file the other one is almost the same but has corrected room numbers of our co-workers - some of our co-workers had to leave their rooms due to maintenance that will last for a few more months.

There are about 200 rows, each representing a co-worker with a lot of information about him or her.

The values I want to compare are in both workbooks starting at B3 and C3. The column can be shorter or longer, depending if someone leaves or joins the company so the script must not have a static range of values that should be compared. Now what I want to do is: compare all the values from Column B3:B* then get the value adjacent value from column C of my edited file and set it to the the adjacent cell C in the original file.

I tried solving the problem with PowerShell by creating a .txt file called impDat.txt with the IDs and the room numbers. When trying to match each line in impDat.txt with the values in the columns of the Excel file I thought this can be done easier with VBA without addressing the Excel file as a COMObject, then matching these values, save the file, close file whatsoever. I wanted to to have a button in the file to do the work without having to run a PS script.

Thank you all

Comment: Welcome to SO, Oxymoron Klimax. Please post the PowerShell code as text in the question. The `ImportExcel` module may be helpful. https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel

Comment: You are making a query to a database (Excel) with a connection string.  In VBA you already have a workbook open and are querying a different excel file using a connection stream.  With PowerShell you do not have either workbook opened.  Do do a comparison you need two connection strings to open two workbooks.

Comment: Seems like you could use VLOOKUP() for this.  No VBA required.